# Does the Holy Spirit also exist in Islam?

Tags: quran, tafseer, christianity

Christians believe in the Holy Spirit. What does Islam /the Holy Scriptures, the Quran tell us  about the Spirit from Allah?

Answer (score 5):

*Does the Holy Spirit also exist in Islam?* - **Yes, By all means.**

Here are some information about him from Quran and Hadith:

- The Holy spirit is the Angel Gabriel. (By comparing [2:97](http://quran.com/2/97) and [16:102](http://quran.com/16/102) )
- Christians believe the Holy Spirit is a part of the Union of God, aka the Trinity. But in Islam, Allah is the lord of Holy Spirit.

  > A'isha reported that the Messenger of Allah (SAW) used to pronounce while bowing and prostrating himself: *All Glorious, All Holy, Lord of the Angels and **the Spirit.*** <sup>[[ref](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/253)]</sup>
- He was only a supporter to Jesus.

  > Mention, when God said, ‘O Jesus, son of Mary, remember My favor to you and to your mother, be thankful for it; when **I strengthened you with the Holy Spirit**... <sup>([5:110](http://quran.com/5/110) Tafseer al Jalalain)</sup>
- Holy Spirit is the one who brought down The Quran from Allah to our Messenger. [verse [16:102](http://quran.com/16/102)]
- The Holy Spirit is also [mentioned in hadith](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/243) to support a person named Hassan Ibn Thabit.

Answer (score 1):

The holy sprite (روح القدس) is mentioned in 4 verses of Quran. For example:

> And We did certainly give Moses the Torah and followed up after him
>   with messengers. And We gave Jesus, the son of Mary, clear proofs and
>   supported him with the **Pure Spirit**. But is it [not] that every
>   time a messenger came to you, [O Children of Israel], with what your
>   souls did not desire, you were arrogant? And a party [of messengers]
>   you denied and another party you killed. http://tanzil.net/#2:87

The prophets and [Infallible Imams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles) have an extra soul comparing ordinary humans. Using this soul they can see and sense all the world. For example they can easily say what you have eaten for dinner last night or what foods already you have in your home.

> And [make him] a messenger to the Children of Israel, [who will say],
>   'Indeed I have come to you with a sign from your Lord in that I design
>   for you from clay [that which is] like the form of a bird, then I
>   breathe into it and it becomes a bird by permission of Allah. And I
>   cure the blind and the leper, and I give life to the dead - by
>   permission of Allah. **And I inform you of what you eat and what you
>   store in your houses.** Indeed in that is a sign for you, if you are
>   believers. http://tanzil.net/#3:49

Comment: From the second verse that you quoted (3:49) it is clear that the particular ability you refer to in the middle paragraph was only given to Eesa (as), for example, Muhammad (saws) was not given the ability to heal lepers.